# Deploy to Azure App Service from a specific folder of External Git

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I have successfully configured Azure App deployment from External Git (which in my case is GitLab) when deploying from the root of the repo.
The thing is that there would be other files an folders in the same repository, so I would like to move the application (in the current case PHP) into a separate folder (i.e. app/) and deploy from there.
I am struggling for the last two days and cannot find a solution. I have tried adding Application settings - PROJECT, but it didn't do the work. Also experimented with DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE using as value app/, app/*, pointing to ZIP file and etc., but no success.

Am I missing something? Or it could be completely different approach ...

I have no developer background so I am not really aware on the specifics of app deployment and configuration, so any help would be apricated.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. In your Azure App Service, go to "Deployment Center" and select "External Git".
2. Copy the deployment URL and Git credentials.
3. In your local development environment, navigate to the root of your Git repository and run the following commands:

   git remote add azure "deployment-url"

   git push azure "local-branch":master
4. In your Azure App Service, go to "Configuration" and add an Application Setting with the key "PROJECT" and the value set to the name of your PHP application directory (i.e. "app/").
5. Save the configuration changes and your PHP application should now be deployed from the subdirectory.

---

**UPDATE:**
Well I did some research about your issue. there are a few alternative approaches you can try:

- Specify the folder path directly in the deployment source: Instead of using the PROJECT application setting, you can specify the folder path directly in the deployment source configuration. Follow these steps:

  In the Azure portal, navigate to your App Service resource. Under the
  "Settings" section, select "Deployment Center". Choose your GitLab
  repository as the source. In the "Configure" step, look for the
  "Repository" field and append the folder path to the repository URL. For
  example, if your repository URL is
- https://gitlab.com/yourusername/yourrepository.git, change it to
- https://gitlab.com/yourusername/yourrepository.git/app/.

  Continue with the deployment process and Azure will deploy the PHP
  application from the specified folder.

2. Modify the deployment script: If the above approach doesn't work, you can modify the deployment script to move the files to the desired folder before the deployment process begins. Follow these steps:

   In your GitLab repository, locate the deployment script file (e.g.,
   .deployment, .deploy.cmd, or .deploy.sh).

   Open the deployment script file and add commands to move the files to the
   desired folder before the deployment process. For example, you can use
   the following command in a .deployment file:

   [config]

   project = app/

   postDeploymentActions = move.cmd

   Create a new file named move.cmd (for Windows) or move.sh (for Linux) in
   the root of your repository.

   In the move.cmd or move.sh file, add the command to move the files to the
   desired folder. For example, for Windows, you can use the following
   content in move.cmd:

   @echo off

   move * app/

   Commit and push the changes to your GitLab repository.
   Azure App Service will execute the deployment script and move the files
   to the app/ folder before deploying the PHP application.

By using one of these approaches, you should be able to deploy your PHP application from a separate folder (app/) in your GitLab repository. Remember to check the deployment logs in the Azure portal for any error messages or further troubleshooting if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried with PROJECT = app/ specified in Application settings, but with no success: Error: Could not find the .NET Core project file.
I have tried as well: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site
Creating .deployment.ini file in the root of the repo with content:
[config]
project = app/
but nothing really happens.